# Choppy images in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I made an iOS game using GLES 2.0 for iOS. When I run it on an actual device, it works perfectly with my high-res images, but when I run it in the simulator, I get very choppy images:

[image: choppy]

I haven't really cared during development, but now that I am going to submit to the iTunes Store, I have to upload screenshots for 3.5'' and 4'' iPhones, which I don't have (I've been developing on an iPad). So I decided to use simulator, but I honestly can't use these screenshots.

Short of buying 3.5'' and 4'' devices *just* to take the screenshots, how can I fix this and get good quality screenshots?

Note: The original images are of huge quality. They don't look choppy at all even on the retina iPad.

Comment: I think you should lower the images' sizes for the iPhone. It looks like they are too big and the simulator doesn't do a good job downsampling, although the devices does.

Comment: @jv42 Is there a way to get good quality up/downsampling on the simulator? I'm not going to manually recreate all of my assets, and recalculate all rendering coordinates to target a smaller resolution, just to take some screenshots.

Comment: Have you tried the scaling options of the simulator? Maybe when set to 2x or to 0.5x the rendering is better?

Comment: @jv42 Where are the scaling options in the simulator? I can't find them anywhere...

Comment: @rob I tested it an earlier version on a friend's 4GS and it looked and performed flawlessly. Also the ipad simulator looks choppy as well. I carefully profiled my app, and in no case I'm using more than 96MB of uncompressed assets, including sounds, which even works on 3 year old 2.3 droids. I have no doubts the final version will work just as flawlessly on 4GS, which is my minimum target platform.

Comment: @Rob oops, I meant 4S up there. There's no iPhone 4GS.

Comment: Excellent. Sorry for doubting your testing regimen! Certainly resizing large assets has a real impact on performance, but it sounds like it's not enough to impact UX on the device, which is the real issue. Well done. Back to your question: I assume you're building release version and once you've run it once on the simulator, you're then stopping Xcode, and running again, this time starting it manually from the simulator? I'm just trying to think of solutions other than major redesign of assets or a broader performance analysis. Sadly, I think ilmcc is right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the simulator was right all along.

I tried the final version on a friend's iPhone 5, and at first sight it looked okay, but on closer inspection it looked just like the screenshot above. I could verify this by having my friend take a screenshot, and in fact looks just like the screenshot I posted up there.

The reason why it looks good on the iPad is because on the iPad, the game is actually upscaling the textures even if just slightly, and the upscaling algorithm yields better results than the downscaling one. (I can swear it looks pretty good on 480x320 2.3 droids)

So anyways, I started fixing the problem by creating mipmaps at loading time with

```
GL.GenerateMipmap(TextureTarget.Texture2D);
```

And then setting the downscaling to use these mipmaps with

```
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)All.LinearMipmapLinear);
```

And now the choppy downscaling is gone, but replaced by a smudgy one. orz

Actually doing this revealed that I was incorrectly using the support for retina displays. The app was running with the resolution of an iPhone 3GS.

So I just had to make sure the framebuffer was created with the correct size, and the problem was gone. However, with retina display, I was upscaling my textures again, so I left the mipmap creation (which consumes more VRAM and makes the game slower to load) only on non-retina devices.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected/known behavior. The simulator is just that: a *simulator* and not an *emulator*. OpenGL performance and image quality in the simulator is often much different (and often worse) than on actual devices. The only way to be sure how OpenGL code will look and perform on the device is to test it on the device, and the only way to get good screen shots in your case will be to hunt down such a device and use it to take a screenshot.  Otherwise, as far as the simulator goes, what you see is what you get. There's no magic switch that says "make this look like it would on the device."

Comment: Funny, the equivalent for android (virtual devices) have very accurate visual quality

Comment: Given the wide variety of graphics hardware across the Android ecosystem, I find it hard to believe that their simulator is able to accurately mimic all the different devices, but I don't do Android development, so I wouldn't know.

Comment: The easiest way to think about it is this: Since the graphics hardware in the host machine is not the same exact graphics hardware as is in the devices, there's no way for simulator graphics to be exactly the same as device graphics. It's always going to be a "best effort" type of thing.

Comment: I understand if it can't accurately simulate the most obscure nuances of the device's gpu, but opengles smoothing is pretty basic and I'm surprised it doesn't work by design.